# how to manage a simple cart session in symfony 2?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, session, cart

im trying to make a simple cart in symfony2, but the documentation about session is very limited and the only example i have found are about user.

from what i understand in watching videos is that have to make this steps:

1-make sure to have a session array, if not declare a new session array
2-add variables to the session array via array_push();
3-display session

this is my code so far:

```
public function sessiontestAction(Request $request)
{  

$session = $request->getSession();
if(!$session)
{
   $session->set('producto');  
}

 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $producto = $em->getRepository('savaInventarioBundle:TblProductos')->find(29);

     if(!$producto){
         throw $this->createNotFoundException('no se encontro el producto');
     }

     array_push($session, $producto);

  return $this->render('savaInventarioBundle:Catalogo:sessiontest.html.twig',
           array('productos'=> $session));
}
```

my output just throws 1 product instead more then one every time i invoke the function, also it shows this error "Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->getSession()` returns an object (instance of [Session](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html) which implements [SessionInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html)), [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function receives an array as first argument (`array_push (array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ])`), of course you can't use array_push function here.

I think the solution will be creating an array, set this array to session, second time retreive it back from session modify it and store it back into session, for example:

```
$session = $request->getSession();

$myArray = array(
    FIRST_ELEMENT
);

$session->set('cartElements', $myArray);

....

$cartElements = $session->get('cartElements');

array_push($cartElements, 'SECOND_ELEMENT');

$session->set('cartElements', $cartElements);

....
```

Answer (score 2):

so after some testing i solved my question. if you ever want to use array_push() to manage session in symfony 2, you can do it like this.

symfony2 manages session and you shouldnt do it with $_SESSION, this is how i can push arrays in the session.

public function sessiontestAction(Request $request) {

```
    $productos = array();

   // $session = $request->getSession();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    //check if the session have products
    if ($session->has('producto')) {
        $productos = $session->get('producto');
        array_push($productos, "tomate", "lechuga");
        $session->set('producto', $productos);
    } //if it doesnt create the session and push a array for testing
    else{
        $test = array("orange", "banana");
        $session->set('producto', $test);
    }
```

//in order to pass an array from the session, you have to set it on a new array.
        $productos = $session->get('producto');
        return $this->render('savaInventarioBundle:Catalogo:sessiontest.html.twig', array('productos' => $productos));
    }

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: i asked for 3 things, 
1-make sure to have a session array, if not declare a new session array(your answer lacks this)

2-add variables to the session array via array_push(); 

3-display session

symfony manages session in a different way, i didnt know about session->has() and wanted to learn how to manage session, i already knew the logic behind of what i wanted, but didnt know the functions, had to figure out those things.

Answer (score 0):

get the session like this: $session = $request->getSession();

and set the parameters in session like this: $session->set('session_var_name', $var);

and get the parameters in session like this: $request->get('session_var_name');

I hope this help you!